# Laravel 9 - Metadata creation using middleware?

Tags: performance, php, laravel

I wrote a middleware for laravel that grabs the current metadata for the specific URL you visit. 

**How it works:**
we use the `$request` and compare the current URL: `$request->getRequestUri()` with the `URL` in the database table:
[image]

So a User visits e.g. `/features/landing` my code would display the metadata (keywords, description) for the `/features/landing` in the database.

Middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class CreateMetadata
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {

        $metadata = DB::table('seos')
            ->where('url', '=', $request->getRequestUri())
            ->first();

        view()->share('metadata', $metadata);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

how I call it in my `web.php` router (wrapped over all pages!):

```
Route::middleware([CreateMetadata::class])->group(function () {
```

then I have a component `meta.blade.php` I call on all pages:

```
@if(isset($metadata))
    {{-- primary meta tags --}}
    <title>{{$metadata->title}}</title>
    <meta name="title" content="{{$metadata->title}}">
    <meta name="description" content="{{$metadata->description}}">
@endif
```

**Question:**
Is this a good practice? Are there better ways to implement this *feature*?
Because if we look at the waterfall of the code execution this currently takes by FAR the biggest time on the website:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Do you know if there are any indexes on the database table e.g. on the `url` column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Redis

If you really need to use specific data and you don't have other ways to do it you can use [Redis](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/redis).

### Misc improvements

- **(Not sure if this works with Laravel 9)** You also should not save direct URL but instead route name with:

```php
\Request::route()->getName()
```

This will allow you to change URL of your pages easily and not having to go in your database every time you change a URL.

- If you don't need every field from your app, use `select title, description` instead of `select *`: this can increase transfer speed (especially if your database server is not local).

Sources (on Stack Overflow):

- [Laravel: How to Get Current Route Name?](//stackoverflow.com/a/33009531/18640839)
- [Which is faster, `SELECT *` or `` SELECT `field` `` ?](//stackoverflow.com/a/4203383/18640839)